# What is the easiest way to get the first stage F-statistic from an feols model?

Tags: r, fixest

I am trying to extract the first stage F-statistic from an IV model run using `feols` in R. My ultimate goal is to report the statistic in a table exported using `etable`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The name of the first-stage F statistic is "ivf", and can be accessed via the `fitstat` function.

Example:

```
reg = feols(Sepal.Length ~ 1 | Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
# get the first-stage F statistic
fitstat(reg, "ivf")

# produce a table that includes the first-stage F statistic
etable(reg, fitstat='ivf')
```